# SQL - Need help translating schema into tables, foreign keys, primary keys

Tags: sql, datatables, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

I've been struggling with looking at a schema and translating that into a relational database model. If this is my schema, how should my tables, primary keys, and foreign keys look or in other words what is the best database design for this particular schema? I am looking for feedback that either what I have is correct or if it is not, why that's the case. I made 5 tables TechCompany, Images, Urls, Tags, & FriendIds. I added 3 columns to TechCompany: Url_Id, Tag_Id, Friend_Id. I made them primary keys and I mapped them to my Id's from my Urls, Tags, and FriendIds tables. The Id's from those tables are my foreign keys.

TechCos < = (1 to 1) => Images
TechCos < = (M to M) => Urls
TechCos < = (M to M) => Tags
TechCos < = (M to M) => Friend_Ids

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "profile": "string",
  "summary": "string",
  "headline": "string",
  "contactInformation": "string",
  "slug": "string",
  "statusId": "NotSet",
  "images": [
    {
      "imageTypeId": 0,
      "imageUrl": "string"
    }
  ],
  "urls": [
    "string"
  ],
  "tags": [
    "string"
  ],
  "friendIds": [
    0
  ]
}
```

[image: ERD of the preceding code]

Comment: I'm sure you're gonna clear this up for me but yeah as of right now without help I wouldn't know whether I need to have one reference table each for Urls, Tags, & FriendIds or if it would be better to have just one reference table to reference TechCompanies to Urls, Tags, & FriendIds. I actually would be kinda shocked if the correct solution was to have a reference table each for Urls, Tags, & FriendIds cause that would be 8 tables total. That just seems like an excessive amount of tables.

Comment: It's good that you gave the text of your design [not just an ERD picture of it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)., but that format is hard to read compared to DDL & you don't actually clearly say that that dump of code it is your design. Since it is, I will put your image inline.

Answer (score 0):

Assume we start with `techcos`:

`techcos (techcos_id PK)`

If `tags` refer to `techcos`, we do something like the following:

`tags (tag_id PK, techcos_id references techcos (techcos_id))`

If the relationship is `One to One`, we can add a `unique constraint` on `tags.techcos_id`, so that no two `tags` can refer to the same `techcos` row.

`tags (tag_id PK, techcos_id references techcos (techcos_id), unique (techcos_id))`

If the relationship is `One to Many`, we can leave out that `unique constraint`, so that more than one `tag` can refer to the same `techcos_id`.

`tags (tag_id PK, techcos_id references techcos (techcos_id))`

If the relationship is `Many to Many`, so that more than one `tag` can refer to the same `techcos_id` and more than one `techcos` can refer to the same `tag`, we need a separate table for these mappings.

`techcos_tags ( techcos_id, tag_id )`, and we remove the `techcos_id` reference from the `tags` table.

We would now have:

`techcos      (techcos_id PK)`

`tags         (tag_id PK)`

`techcos_tags ( techcos_id, tag_id )`, along with a `primary key constraint` (or `unique constraint`) on the pair `(techcos_id, tag_id)` to avoid duplication.

All other relationships between tables will likely follow similar patterns.

Feel free to clarify your above problem and I'll expand on this, if needed.

Comment: There's nothing else to clarify you answered my question. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have a question. Let's take stackOverflow for example. On their Question Submission page at the bottom you can add tags. So in that situation on the back end is the relationship between each question submission and the tags attached to them a M-to-M relationship or a 1-to-M relationship?

Comment: That would be many to many, since each tag could be associated with more than one submission and one submission can have many tags.

Comment: A few more questions. On my TechCos_Tags table aren't both columns (techCos_Id and tag_Id) supposed to be a PK and a FK? And I am trying to start creating my tables and doing everything inside new queries rather than "designing" tables manually but for some reason SSMS complains when i try to make both columns in my TechCos_Tags table a PK? I don't get it a primary key can consist of one or more columns. Does it have something to do with my "CONSTRAINT TechCos_Id UNIQUE(Tag_Id)" statement?

Comment: Nevermind I did PRIMARY KEY (TechCos_Id, Tag_Id) and that worked but right after that I tried UNIQUE (TechCos_Id, Tag_Id) and I get an incorrect syntax expecting '(' or SELECT warning.

Comment: LOL nevermind I was missing a coma. Oops.